# How to strip exports during build for GAS process? Need to use exports in local unit testing with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, google-apps-script, jestjs, automated-tests

Trying to use Jest for local unit & integration testing. I already have some npm scripts to build the GAS-compatible code and upload it with clasp so that's not an issue.

The problem is seemingly simple but I can't figure out the best way to handle removing the exports that Jest requires to work.

For example say I start with a super simple script like this in my **sum.js** file:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
```

If I want to add a test to that function I add `module.exports = sum` which will result in a **sum.js** file like this:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
module.exports = sum
```

And then write my tests in a **sum.test.js** file, something like this:

```
import { add } from "./index.js"

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

The problem is `module.exports = sum` and `export { sum }` create an exception in Google Apps Scripts (won't even upload with clasp), so I just want an easy way to remove all exports during the build process that's not a super hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to achieve the same thing and it is a painstaking journey. Jest was a no go unfortunately.
At the moment I am working with QUnit in Node.js for local testing and the GAS QUnit v2 library for Google side testing.
To strip export and import statements, It's been suggested to me to look at rollup with plugins such as [this](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/strip) or [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-strip-import-export).

Comment: This should have been a comment instead of an answer because it contains resources to start with but no ultimate solution.

Comment: I don't have 50 reputation to comment apparently

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30305460)